# Passing router outlet variable to parent component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Main component:

```
<main-component>
  <sub-menu [menuItems]="routerlist"></submenu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main-component>
```

router-outlet template (typescript):

I have declared a variable to push items into a menu
Inside my constructor or nginit I have this code (routerlist is declared above the constructor)

```
const _routerlist: any[] = [];
_routerlist.push({ route: '#', title: 'menu-item-001'});
this.routerlist = _routerlist
```

My question is how do I pass routerlist to the main component so the sub menu can use it?

Comment: as you did for submenu like : `<main [menuItems]="routerlist"></main>`

Comment: Why aren't you subscribing to the router in `<sub-menu/>`? It's much easier to do and components have no dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a service for the menu.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SubmenuService {

  private menuItems = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);
  public menuItems$: Observable<any>;

  updateSubmenu(data: any[]) {
    this.menuItems.next(data);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.menuItems$ = this.menuItems.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In the component where I declared the submenu I subscribed to the menu:

```
<sub-menu [menuItems]="subMenuItems"></sub-menu>
```

and in the "router-outlet" component the items are set.
Router-outlet component ts:

```
updateSubmenu(): void {
    const _routerlist: any[] = [];
    _routerlist.push(
      { route: '/somepath', title: 'menu item 001' },
      { route: '/someotherpath', title: 'menu item 002' },
    );

    this.submenuService.updateSubmenu(_routerlist);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the reouterList directly  as you mention and you can get routerlist from sub-menu to main-component using `@Output` as  below

```
<main-component [menuItems]="routerlist">
  <submenu [menuItems]="routerlist" (getRouterList)= getRouterList($event)></submenu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this stackblitz link. [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbqeop)

- **Here, first**

Default component C is loaded in `<router-outlet>`. then using `(activate)` event we can get data of EventEmitter and pass data to app.component.ts function called `outputListEmitter(event)`, we have to subscribe here to get data of emitted value.

- **second case,**

  is normal manual component defined in template, and same eventemitter is used to get data to app.component.ts and pass to template. to check this feature you have to click button of b.component so, value changes is displaying there in app.component.html.